# Samba shares don't work

Tags: networking, permissions, nautilus, samba

Ubuntu 20:04LTS
It have being a very strange error with my samba shares, after an update yesterday.
First I can not sambashare a folder home/Downloads/TDL. Nautilus give an error (fig1)

Fist I can not share a file in my home directory any more. I get this error when I try to share from nautilus:
[image: When i try to share folder TDL i get this error message]

Why can i not share folders with Nautilus share? Nautilus says:

'*'net usershare' returned error 255: [2023/04/03 15:42:47,  0] ../../lib/util/debug.c:1100(reopen_one_log)
reopen_one_log: Unable to open new log file 'TDL/log.net': No such file or directory
net usershare add: share name /home/a/downloads/tdl contains invalid characters (any of %<>*?|/+=;:",)*'

I can not find any invalid charters in my name of chared folders

When i looking for shared folder with:
'net usershare info --long' I get no shares folders even if I have shared "media" read only in smb.conf by adding:

[Media-guest]
path = /media
;       read only = yes
force user =
guest ok = yes

in the end of smb.conf

This work, I can access my usb-disks as read only, but it does not show up with net usershare and I can not make any share with nautilus.

/Cheers

Comment: I believe this is a [known bug in `samba`](https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15145).

Comment: So there are no solution? Well for a long time Samba browsing did not work (about half a year) so maybe I have to edit in smb.conf again. Is there solution if you aktivate Ubuntu Pro?